# Sending notification email based on query results

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a query table which shows the "FirstName", "LastName", "DueDate". What I wanted to do is create a follow-up process. If the duedate is today (date()), access needs to send notification email to the one general email address.

My code works only for first record in the query, it doesn't goes to other records.

Here is the code that I am using for;

```
Public Sub FollowUpEmail()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim oApp As Object
Dim oEmail As Object

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(0)


Set db = CurrentDb
                strSQL = "SELECT FirstName, SurName, DueDate" & _
                            " FROM TestQuery"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)


While Not rs.EOF
SendKeys "^{ENTER}"
With oEmail
.To = "xxx"
.Subject = rs.Fields("FirstName").Value & "/" & "Deadline"
.Body = "test"
.Display

End With
rs.MoveNext
Wend


rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing


Set oApp = Nothing
Set oEmail = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: You have rs.MoveNext outside the While/Wend loop. I'm surprised it isn't hanging because you will never reach EOF in the while loop!

Comment: I put it inside the loop but it gives an error again. it is sending the email for the first record but when it comes to second record, "the item has been removed or deleted " error show up for .Subject = rs.Fields("FirstName").Value line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create & send a new email for every iteration of the loop, for example:

```vb
Public Sub FollowUpEmail()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Dim oApp As Object
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT FirstName, SurName, DueDate FROM TestQuery")

    Do Until rs.EOF
        With oApp.CreateItem(0)
            .To = "xxx"
            .Subject = rs!FirstName & "/" & "Deadline"
            .Body = "test"
            .Display
        End With
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Or, if you want to send the emails directly:

```vb
Public Sub FollowUpEmail()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Dim oApp As Object
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT FirstName, SurName, DueDate FROM TestQuery")

    Do Until rs.EOF
        With oApp.CreateItem(0)
            .To = "xxx"
            .Subject = rs!FirstName & "/" & "Deadline"
            .Body = "test"
            .Send
        End With
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked perfectly. I have one small problem. Is there a way to hide display screen? .send command does not work for security reason, i guess. Thats why I am using  SendKeys "^{ENTER}". Do you think is there a alternative way to do this without showing the display screen?

Comment: @mesakon I've updated my answer above. When you state that the `.Send` method "does not work", do you receive an error? I use this technique frequently in my applications with no trouble at all.